# SpringBoot: get object current value stored in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with spring boot, let's say I have a method "update" to update the record of a Person. I am making fixes over somebody else's code so this is just the way things are. I am simplifying things here but the function has way more validations and things I don't want to change. The thing is, that between all those things this method does, it copies the values of the changedPersona to the object of persona stored in the database at the time.

What I need to do is check if some specific fields from changedPersona are different to the ones stored for that person in the database. That I try to do in the "checkChanges" function, the problem is that even though I try to get the value of personaBefore fresh out of the database, Spring boot returns the object with the attributes of changedPersona (because of the copying in the "update" function I did before). So the comparison doesn't work.

Notice that the updated values are not being officially stored in the database until AFTER I call the checkChanges function.

```java
@Override
public void update(Persona changedPersona){
    Persona personaBefore = this.personaRepository.findById(changedPersona.getId());
    // because of the way this method was written personaBefore will eventualy have the same values as changedPersona
    copyAttributesOfObjectAToObjectB(changedPersona, personaBefore);
    .
    .
    .
    //this is what i need to do 
    checkChanges(changedPersona);

    this.personaRepository.save(changedPersona);


}

private void checkChanges(Persona changedPersona){
    Persona personaBefore = this.personaRepository.findById(changedPersona.getId());
    if(changedPersona.equals(personaBefore){
    // do something
    }
}
```

I need a way to get the personaBefore object CURRENT value in the database, not as it is stored in spring boot memory. Something like

```java
 var personaBefore = this.personaRepository.findRealTimeValueById(changedPersona.idPersona);
```

Help please

Comment: IF you are using SQL database, have you tried using a `nativeQuery`?

Comment: you already have the data of your `personaBefore` in your `update` method, so why don't you pass it as second parameter to your `checkChanges` method? You even could make a copy of it. Or you detach the instance from the database, so it doesn't get updates from there. (Fetch it, detach it, keep it for further reference)

Comment: You have to think of the in-memory representation of DB attached objects as a cache of the DB. Never try to work around this as long as the object is attached to the DB! It will bring you more trouble than it will help.

Comment: @JettoMartínez yes, It doesn't work, it returns the value with the copied attributes of changedPersona

Comment: @cyberbrain I know, I found a way to work around it like that. But since I need to call the checkChanges function in other functions as well, I would like a cleaner more straightforward way to do it.

Comment: If both `persona` will have the same attributes after the `copyAttributesOfObjectAToObjectB` method is called, and that call is complicating your requirement, why can't you check before it? I mean, as the method signature implies, `changedPersona` attributes are copied to `personaBefore`, right? If so, then check before that happens. Your method is supposed to only **check**, so it can return a boolean and after the copying, do whatever your `if` statement is supposed to if needed.

Comment: @JettoMartínez I know there are other solutions, what I am asking is if there is a good, recommended way of discarding the personaBefore stored in spring-boot memory, so that I can get the actual value stored in the database.

Comment: Although you are not indicating persistence framework, I would suggest to check if your assumption on "equality" method is correct. Check implementation of "equals" method on  Persona  class.

Comment: Does the method `copyAttributesOfObjectAToObjectB` also modify its first parameter, `changedPersona`?